# iOS8 how to fix "Health data is unavailable on this device" when using HealthKit on iPad Air

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, healthkit

I'm trying to run the "Fit" example from WWDC 2014 to check out the HealthKit. I'm using iPad air updated to iOS8 beta3. However, when entering any info, the app crashes with the error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=1 "Health data is unavailable on this device"
```

Here's an example of a method producing error

```
    - (void)saveHeightIntoHealthStore:(double)height {
        // Save the user's height into HealthKit.
        HKUnit *inchUnit = [HKUnit inchUnit];
        HKQuantity *heightQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:inchUnit doubleValue:height];

        HKQuantityType *heightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        HKQuantitySample *heightSample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:heightType quantity:heightQuantity startDate:now endDate:now];

        [self.healthStore saveObject:heightSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (!success) {

//Error reported here

                NSLog(@"An error occured saving the height sample %@. In your app, try to handle this gracefully. The error was: %@.", heightSample, error);
                abort();
            }
            [self updateUsersHeight];
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HealthKit is not available on iPads, only iPhones and iPods - just like Passbook.

Comment: source ? pretty please

Comment: From the HKHealthStore.h header: _HealthKit is not supported on all iOS devices.  Using HKHealthStore APIs on devices which are not supported will result in errors with the HKErrorHealthDataUnavailable code.  Call isHealthDataAvailable before attempting to use other parts of the framework._